# Function to count decimal places with PHP

Tags: php, math

Is there a native PHP function which tells me how many decimal places a number has, or will I have to make my own?

```
IE:
0.8 -> 1
0.2345 -> 4
0.894 -> 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to make your own if you really want that function. It shouldn't be all that hard, though - just convert to a string, `explode()` on the `.`, and then take the length of the second element in the array.

Beware of floating point inaccuracy, though.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not stored as strings - they're stored as base-2 numbers. What that means is that any decimal which isn't based on powers of 2 is actually stored as an approximation (for instance, 0.3 isn't stored as 'exactly' 0.3, but instead some combination of powers of 2 that is very close to 0.3). Thus, if you input `0.3`, you might get something like `0.2999999999999994` back, which obviously has a very different number of digits after the decimal point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are stored in binary, they don't "have" any number of decimal places.  They are converted to decimal representation as part of printing them.  How many places are printed depends on the formatting function used to print them.